# If the Marvel Zombies hadn't turned Wolverine, could his healing factor have been utilized to supply them with meat indefinitely?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, wolverine

Since he can regrow tissue/muscle/etc., seems as if he would be a perfect self-regenerating source of food.

Comment: What happens to someone when they get bitten by a zombie?

Comment: Op means They could just keep chopping his legs and arms off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR : The concept seems sound at first glance, but ultimately would not work in practice.**

---

Technically, what you propose might be possible - Wolverine himself has fought off starvation by eating his own flesh (which would then heal back). In New X-Men #148, he tells Jean that one time he was trapped under a glacier for six months and survived by cutting strips off of his arm and eating them.

Similar to how Hank Pym kept himself lucid

> by cutting pieces off of the uninfected (and sedated) Black Panther

, it might be possible to keep Logan as a self-sustaining food source. However, there are multiple issues with this approach:

- Logan himself would need a constant influx of food and/or nutrients in order to heal
- It takes an inordinate amount of drugs to keep Logan sedated, and the few sedatives that work on him would have to be kept in his system indefinitely to keep him unconscious
- A non-sedated Logan would inevitably escape at some point, as he is quite famous for escaping restraints (and then giving whoever restrained him a bad day)
- Logan could not be fed off of directly, since any bites would turn him into a zombie as well
- The Marvel Zombies are only capable of lucid thought when full. When the hunger takes them, all rational thought is gone, and it's inevitable that one of them would eventually lose control and bite Wolverine directly, thereby contaminating the food source

Assuming that Earth-2149 has the same technology available as on Earth-616, a far better solution for the Marvel Zombies would have been some kind of cloning facility at which they could clone an uninfected human repeatedly. Given the ability to produce instant clones, this would provide an endless supply of uninfected flesh to consume.

Comment: Why would you need to keep him sedated? You have to keep normals sedated to prevent trauma induced death. Maybe to keep them quiet. But restraints and a suitable cave would work when trauma isn't a concern.

Comment: @cde true, but Wolverine has a reputation for escaping restraints, then making those who restrained him have a bad day.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the perfect choice would actually be Multiple Man. Sad for Jamie, good eats for everyone else.

Comment: @Omegacron: Kingpin did actually have a cloning facility, seen in Marvel Zombies volume 3.

Answer (score 3):

Conceivably yes. But not for many. Likely for just one or two. The zombies can think rationally if they eat enough, and they have been known to squirrel away people, er I mean food for that purpose, as Henry Pym did to Black Panther. He locked him up, and sawed of body parts before eating them to prevent Black Panther from being infected.

Wolverine and other healers like Deadpool  have at times been shown to regrow limbs in days (Deadpool has shown this happening to his brain). During the Kid Apocalypse arc of X-Force, Deadpool used the meat from his arm to nurse Angel back to health from being affected by the Horseman Famine.